# Django Model Admin with FileField cannot read file in save_model after reading file when validating

Tags: python, django, validation

I have a model with a `FileField` and I want to read the contents of the file before saving it in the Django admin. I need to verify the file is formatted correctly and also to parse version information out of it and save it into the model. I have written code for validation and can successfully validate the file, but it seems I cannot save the version information from the file in the `save_object` method after i successfully run the validation. If i skip using the validation, the code in the `save_object` method works as expected and I can read the file contents and save the version information into the model. I just can't get them to both work at the same time.

```
# models.py:

# the validation works
def validate_file_contents(value):
        contents = value.read()
        first_line, rest_of_file = contents.split('\n', 1)
        if not validate_file_format(rest_of_file):
            raise ValidationError("File is not formatted correctly.")
        if not parse_version(first_line):
            raise ValidationError("The file does not contain correctly formatted version information.")

class MyModel(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(validators=[validate_file_contents])
    version = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

---

```
# admin.py:

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['file',]
    list_display = ['file', 'version']
    list_filter = ['file', 'version']

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        contents = request.FILES['file'].read()
        # contents is empty after successful validation! It is not empty if validation is skipped.

        first_line = contents.split('\n', 1)[0]
        obj.version = parse_version(first_line)
        obj.save()
```

How can I both validate the file and save the version information? I am using Django 1.10 and Python 2.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read()` works the way that it uses a pointer of position which you are reading from the file. So as you read the file, the pointer moves toward its end, until it's on the very end. So calling `read()` again will return nothing, because you're pointing on the end of the file now.

To read the file again, use `seek(0)` first, which will move the pointer to the start of the file again.